# Trouble hiding all elements with a certain data attribute

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

i'm pretty much a complete js noob, and i'm trying to make a tampermonkey script that removes elements with a certain data attribute. i'm getting this error (`Cannot set property 'display' of undefined`), here's my code

```js
(function() {
    var subscription_elements = [] //all subscription related page elements

    subscription_elements.push(document.querySelectorAll('[data-pulse-paywall-type="subscription"]')); //array, i think
    subscription_elements.push(document.getElementsByClassName('pks-product item'))

    console.log('Paywalled articles:');
    console.log(subscription_elements);

    subscription_elements.forEach(hide_article);

    function hide_article(item, index){
        item.style.display = 'none';
    };
})();
```

Edit: Solved! Unwrapping the array using `...` turned out to be the solution.

Comment: What site is this, so we can test this?

Comment: you are push arrays into the array instead of elements

Comment: You are pushing in an array into an array.... It is not concatenating them so you end up with `[[...,...,...],[...,...,...,...]]`

Comment: Try replacing `push(document` with `push(...document` (the spread syntax should unwrap the arrays, and since `push()` accepts multiple arguments, this should do it)

Comment: The site is ``bt.no``, a local news site.